# Jasperserver - dashboard

Tags: dashboard, jasperserver

How can I remove login page of jasperserver-pro webapp. I want to embedd jasperserver dashboard as an iframe into external dashboard (outside jasperserver)

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 options:

- you allow anonymous access to the dashboard
- you setup some form of authentication:

  - passing `j_username` and `j_password` as URL parameter
  - using single sign on like cas or siteminder
  - creating a custom authentication.

There is an authentication cookbook for JasperReports server available that describes single sign on with cas, the ultimate guide provides details on custom authentication (see [documentation](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation?version=6263)), in the jaspersoft community wiki you will find more examples, e.g. for [siteminder](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/siteminder-configuring-and-integrating-it-jasperreports-server).